# How to enhance a fuzzy image

Tags: image-processing

First I am sorry if this question is duplicate. I am not familiar with image processing so I don't know how to search for answer.

I have an images which were taken with good camera but the camera sometimes produce bad images I don't know why.

I want to enhance some of these images but I don't know how.

Here is one of those not good image:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `Sharpen`, perhaps?

Comment: Sharpen did not help. Still not good looking image.

Comment: ImageAdjust seems to change coloring and brightness. but again I am not getting better image. I will keep trying.

Comment: Blurring is a form of convolution. To undo it, what you want is deconvolution, *i.e.* [`ImageDeconvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageDeconvolve.html). However, your image also has a lot of noise, which makes deconvolution very hard.

Comment: @Rahul I have tried your suggestion now but there is not much effect. I played with GaussianMatrix parameter but for value more than 3 parts of the image start to disappear.

Comment: In practice, if the image is out of focus, there's nothing you can do. The information is permanently lost.

Comment: @Szabolcs That is not good news:(. But how can you tell if the problem is out of focus or something else?

Comment: A disk is a better model for defocus blur than a Gaussian function. Set `r = 6; k = DiskMatrix[r]/Total[DiskMatrix[r], Infinity];` and try `ImageDeconvolve[image, k, Method -> "RichardsonLucy"]` or `ImageDeconvolve[image, k, Method -> {"TotalVariation", "NoiseModel" -> "Laplacian"}]`. The results aren't super fantastic, but they're something.

Comment: @Rahul the first method gives better result compared to the second.

Comment: @Algohi If the image is straight form the camera, I can't imagine what else it could be ...

Comment: Perhaps this should be moved to [DSP.SE] to determine an optimal approach, then a new question could be posted regarding implementation?

Comment: By the way deconvolution can be very effective as seen in the documentation examples, but the starting image must be very clean.  As noted by Rahul the noise here is bad; probably fatal as it were in that too much information is lost beyond the noise threshold.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, ok I will try to use deconvolution  as much as I can to get the best results.

Answer (score 15):

I'll use my own pictures as test cases (click on them to get the full images).  These pictures were taken with a D3300 and MICRO-NIKKOR 40mm 2.8G; settings were f/3.2, 1/6 and 1/800 shutter, ISO 100 and 12800, auto WB.

### In-focus (desired image)

Autofocus locked on to the surface texture of the laptop here.  At this wide aperture the depth-of-field is tiny:you can tell the keys are a little out of focus!

[image]

### Out-of-focus (clean)

For this image I manually set the focus to infinity.

[image]

### Out-of-focus (noisy)

I set the camera to (almost) maximum ISO for this shot, decreasing the shutter speed accordingly.

[image]

The thumbnail doesn't do justice to how noisy this one is; here's a 100% magnification:

[image]

---

I've gone ahead and `Import`ed these images as `infocus`, `badfocus`, and `noisy`, respectively, preprocessing them with:

```
img = ImageResize[ImageRotate[img, Pi], Scaled[1/10]]
```

Downscaling will make things go a lot faster as well as save some memory (Mathematica's image-processing functions are extremely memory-intensive).

We can see from the [bokeh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bokeh) (blur) from the power button light that the [PSF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_spread_function) of the unfocused lens is approximately a uniform disk of diameter around 38 pixels.

Thus we can make a first attempt to deconvolve the image:

```
kernel = DiskMatrix[19];
kernel /= Total[kernel, 2];
ImageDeconvolve[badfocus, kernel]
```

[image]

This is pretty bad, but there's hope: the text of the <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys *are* visible.

The `"Hybrid"` iterative method gives better results:

```
ImageDeconvolve[badfocus, 2 Normalize[DiskMatrix[19], Total[#, 2] &], 
 Method -> {"Hybrid", "Preconditioned" -> True}, MaxIterations -> 50]
```

[image]

`"Tikhonov"` also performs surprisingly well:

```
ImageDeconvolve[badfocus, 
 2 Normalize[DiskMatrix[19.1], Total[#, 2] &], Method -> "Tikhonov"]
```

[image]

Neither are what I'd find *acceptable*, much less *good*; even though this is pretty much the best possible case:

- A totally flat object parallel to the image plane (so that the degree of blur is the same over the whole image)
- Flat bokeh
- Low-noise
- Bright point-like light sources (allowing good estimation of the PSF)
- High-contrast objects, *i.e.* the backlit letters (deconvolution can't recover subtle details)

If we add some noise, `"Hybrid"` fails to resolve any details:

[image]

Although `"Tikhonov"` is a little sharper, it has higher noise:

[image]

Your image represents a worst-case scenario for sharpening:

- A 3d object with spatially-varying blurring
- Unknown and inestimable PSF
- *Very* high noise

Unfortunately every deconvolution method I tried on your image failed completely, severely *worsening* the image quality in all cases.

In summary, **deconvolution can recover *information* in certain cases, but cannot improve image *quality*.**

Even the most expensive camera will produce crap if not used correctly, and even the cheapest disposable camera can produce sharp images: focus *before* you hit the shutter.

Comment: A fine answer, but your summary seems prone to misinterpretation.  I would actually state it conversely: **deconvolution *cannot* add *information* to an image, but it can improve the *intelligibility* of that information**.  Noise, compression, etc., all cause irrecoverable information loss.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the radius of sharpening:

`Sharpen[myImage, 15]`

[image]

Or try this and play around:

```
Manipulate[
 Blur[
  Sharpen[
      ImageAdjust[myImage, c], 
        n], 
       m], 
   {c, .1, 2}, {n, 1, 20, 1}, {m, 2, 20, 1}]
```

Comment: I am trying to get the best parameters but still no much luck.